# Quarkus: Generate bean with a generic bean dependency passed at constructor

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-extension

I would like to know how I can generate a bean having a dependency to an another bean (using generic Type).

I made a sample here: https://github.com/dcdh/quarkus-hello-world-playground

I've got this bean

```
@Singleton
public class DefaultHelloWorld extends HelloWorld<String> {
    public DefaultHelloWorld(final HelloWorldDependency<String> helloWorldDependency) {
        super(helloWorldDependency);
    }

    @Override
    public String sayHello() {
        return "DefaultHelloWorld";
    }
}
```

And I am using this kind of code to generate the java code

```
@BuildStep(onlyIf = ShouldGenerateBean.class)
    void helloWorldGenerator(final BuildProducer<GeneratedBeanBuildItem> generatedBeanBuildItemBuildProducer) {
        final ClassOutput beansClassOutput = new GeneratedBeanGizmoAdaptor(generatedBeanBuildItemBuildProducer);
        final ClassCreator beanClassCreator = ClassCreator.builder().classOutput(beansClassOutput)
                .className(HelloWorld.class.getName() + "Generated")
                .signature(
                        SignatureBuilder.forClass()
                                .setSuperClass(
                                        Type.parameterizedType(
                                                Type.classType(HelloWorld.class),
                                                Type.classType(String.class))))
                .build();
        beanClassCreator.addAnnotation(Singleton.class);
        beanClassCreator.addAnnotation(DefaultBean.class);
        // constructor
        final MethodCreator constructor = beanClassCreator.getMethodCreator(MethodDescriptor.INIT, void.class,
                String.format("%s<%s>", HelloWorldDependency.class.getName(), String.class.getName()));
        constructor.setModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC);
        ResultHandle supportHandle = getFromCDI(constructor, String.format("%s<%s>", HelloWorldDependency.class.getName(), String.class.getName()));
        constructor.invokeSpecialMethod(MethodDescriptor.ofConstructor(HelloWorld.class, HelloWorldDependency.class), constructor.getThis(), supportHandle);
        constructor.returnValue(null);

        // sayHello
        final MethodCreator clazzMethod = beanClassCreator.getMethodCreator("sayHello", Object.class);
        clazzMethod.setModifiers(Opcodes.ACC_PUBLIC);
        clazzMethod.returnValue(clazzMethod.load("HelloWorldGenerated"));
        beanClassCreator.close();
    }

    // https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-langchain4j/blob/main/core/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkiverse/langchain4j/deployment/AiServicesProcessor.java#L627 :)
    private ResultHandle getFromCDI(final MethodCreator mc, final String className) {
        // Arc.container().instance(className).get();
        final ResultHandle containerHandle = mc.invokeStaticMethod(MethodDescriptor.ofMethod(Arc.class, "container", ArcContainer.class));
        final ResultHandle instanceHandle = mc.invokeInterfaceMethod(
                MethodDescriptor.ofMethod(ArcContainer.class, "instance", InstanceHandle.class, Class.class,
                        Annotation[].class),
                containerHandle, mc.loadClassFromTCCL(className),
                mc.newArray(Annotation.class, 0));
        return mc.invokeInterfaceMethod(MethodDescriptor.ofMethod(InstanceHandle.class, "get", Object.class), instanceHandle);
    }
```

If you have a look to the previous commit it is working fine when the HelloWorldDependency dependency is not a generic.

To make it work I am using Arc to retrieve the bean. However, the bean is resolved at runtime and so Generic is no more available. Should I generate and use Qualifier ?

Is there an another way to generate bean using a Quarkus build item ?
I was expected to make it works without using Arc but it seems that it is not possible.

Regards,
Damien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when I look at the `quarkus-hello-world-playground` project it seems that the gizmo code for the `HelloWorldGenerated` constructor is the problem.

First, you need to set the method signature to reflect the generic parameters. Also the `HelloWorldPlaygroundProcessor#getFromCDI()` is useless because you don't need to lookup the bean programmatically if using constructor injection - the bean instance is injected in the constructor argument.

The code should look like:

```java
MethodCreator constructor = beanClassCreator.getMethodCreator(MethodDescriptor.INIT, void.class, HelloWorldDependency.class);
constructor.setSignature(
                SignatureBuilder.forMethod()
                        .addParameterType(Type.parameterizedType(Type.classType(HelloWorldDependency.class), Type.classType(String.class)))
                        .setReturnType(Type.voidType())
                        .build());
constructor.setModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC);
constructor.invokeSpecialMethod(MethodDescriptor.ofConstructor(HelloWorld.class, HelloWorldDependency.class), constructor.getThis(), constructor.getMethodParam(0));
constructor.returnVoid();
```

Comment: It works like a charm. I've just updated my sample for the ones interested. Many thanks.